# 3-sphere bundle over 7-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am not able to understand why the first mod $3$ Steenrod reduced power operation is an isomorphism from the $3^\mbox{rd}$ cohomology of $M$ to 7th cohomology of $M$ while reading Theorem 1 of the paper available at arxiv:math/0011178v2, where $M$ = total space of 3-sphere bundle over 7-sphere.

Can someone give some answers to the above question?